# Index Error: too many indices for array While defining variable

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I received this message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-60bbe78150c2> in <module>()
      17 men_only_stats=data[0::4]!="male"
      18 
 ---> 19 women_onboard = data[women_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)
      20 men_onboard = data[men_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)
      21 proportion_women_survive= sum(women_onboard)/size(women_onboard)

 IndexError: too many indices for array
```

when I enter my code here:

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open(r"C:\Users\IT'S OVER 9000\Downloads\train.csv", 'rb'))
header = csv_file_object.next() 
data=[]

for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data=np.array(data)

number_passengers= np.size(data[0::4,1].astype(np.float))
passengers_survived=np.sum(data[0::4,1].astype(np.float))
proportion_survived=passengers_survived/number_passengers

women_only_stats= data[0::4]=="female"
men_only_stats=data[0::4]!="male"

women_onboard = data[women_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)     
men_onboard = data[men_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)
proportion_women_survive= sum(women_onboard)/size(women_onboard)
proportion_men_survive= sum(men_onboard)/size(men_onboard)
print proportion_women_survive
print proportion_men_survive
```

Here are two lines of data from my cvs file:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked,‌​,,, 
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,,S,,,     
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC,17599,71.2833,C85,C,,,
```

What did I do wrong, what caused it, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't `men_only_stats` use `=="male"`?

Comment: In the data set I have, there are only two categories: "male" and "female".
If I put != "female" then python will grab the data with the gender index that is not female. But switching it to male accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: And it looks like both your variables contain female. `!= "male"` is the same thing as `== "female"`, isn't it?

Comment: oops. thanks for your help!
Huh, just tried switching the variables and made 
    men_only_stats= data[0::4] =="male"
but i still get the indeces error.

Comment: what is the`1` in  `women_only_stats,1` supposed to be? Get only the first column?

Comment: Yes. It was supposed to grab only the first column.

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like, an example?

Comment: is it cool if I pm it to you? The data isn't sensitive.

Comment: sure, but how would you *pm* ? I would say you jut need an example data (does not need to be your real data) , that structurely looks same as your original data (a few rows would do).

Comment: Oh, there isn't a function like that here. Ok, well, here's two lines of the data from the cvs file.

          PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked,,,,
    1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5,21171,7.25,,S,,,
    2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC,17599,71.2833,C85,C,,,

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Comment: data in the question now. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the issue in when you take the bool arrays (for indexing)  -

```
women_only_stats= data[0::4]=="female"
```

I believe `data` is a 2D array, hence `data[0::4]` takes the every 4th row from the array (not the 4th column), and then you try to compare that with the string value, hence you get back an 2D array of True/False values. This causes the issue.

Actually what you want to do would be -

```
women_only_stats = data[:,4]=="female"
```

Same for `men_only_stats` , also you should reconsider everywhere where you have used `[0::4]` , this means every 4th element from that dimension.

Also , finally I would like suggest that for such kind of csv/data manipulation , it would be far easier to use pandas library than numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The error `IndexError: too many indices for array` happens when you try to access a 1d array as though it were 2d, or a 2d array as though it were 3d, etc.

In this case you are accessing `data`, a 1d array. The line throwing the error:

```
women_onboard = data[women_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)
```

...is using the syntax `array_var[x,y]`, which can only be used for a 2d+ array. That syntax means you are accessing the element at row `x` and column `y`, so it doesn't apply to an array that has only one row (or only one column if you think of it that way).

If you search for that error message, you'll get lots of results of people asking similar questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199585/indexerror-too-many-indices-numpy-array-with-1-row-and-2-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108909/indexerror-too-many-indices-in-numpy-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array).