# Column vector with for loop and if statement - IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to create a binary column vector (y3) based on a comparison of two lists. For each element of both list, if one is bigger than the other, 0, if not ,1. The result (ones and zeroes) being stored in y3.

```
t=5
list1 = data[:t,0]  # Extrated from data = np.array(list(...
list2 = data[:t,1]  # Same
for i in range(t):
    if list1[i]<=list2[i]:
        y3[i]=0
    else:
        y3[i]=1
```

I get an "IndexError: too many indices for array". What is wrong with the code?
Thank you for your valuable help.

Comment: Plz have a look at the "related" questions and see if you find solution there...e.g.,: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199585/indexerror-too-many-indices-numpy-array-with-1-row-and-2-columns?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108909/indexerror-too-many-indices-in-numpy-python?rq=1

Comment: Checked, from what I see their problem stems from having 1 row, which is not my case (t rows). If having 1 column generates the same issue, I am a bit unclear as to how I need to reshape list1 and list2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which line in the code throws the error? What might be the case is that you did not define y3 before indexing it. Did you write

```
y3=np.ndarray(5)
```

somewhere? Secondly, you might want to use list comprehension and a ternary operator to make the code more concise and pythonic. This replaces the whole loop:

```
y3=[0 if list1[i]<=list2[i] else 1 for i in range(t)]
```

In which case defining of y3 beforehand is also not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly answers the questions